# Ajax - $.get data from server

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to get the city name based on the zip code given by user in an input field.

This input, and ajax function:

```
<input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code" 
onkeyup="
  $.get('<?=$config['url']?>/ajax/location/?code='+this.value, 
  function(data){ $('#location').html(data); });" 
  maxlength="5" />
```

This is the /ajax/location/?code= file:

```
 <?php
    $city = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postal_codes WHERE postal_code = '" . intval($_GET['code']) . "'")); 
 ?>
 <div>
   <p>
      <input value="<?php echo $city->city_name; ?>" name="city"  />
   </p>
</div>
```

I used .ajaxError to see the error, but it doesn't help. It alerts only the url and no information about the error.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
            alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \n'+'error:\n' + xhr.responseText );
            });
```

This is what ajaxError alert:

```
error in: http://mywebsitename.com/ajax/location/?code=11824 
error:
```

I tried to get a .txt file using $.get and it worked. So I'm 100% sure that ajax is working properly.

Thanks.

Comment: are you requesting the data from the same server on which the script is originated ?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same server.

Comment: No error. The ajax request fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

The problem was:

```
<?=$config['url']?>
```

Absolute url. I removed that and it worked.

```
'/ajax/location/?code='+this.value
```

Thanks everyone for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

the /ajax/location/?code= not have a db connection

### EDIT:

try this:

```
$.get('<?=$config['url']?>/ajax/location/', {code:this.value}, function(data){ $('#location').html(data); });
```